# Using XSL transform, how do I only return XML elements that require a change

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XLM that I need to process with XSL, my code concatenates several elements to the description element but the output needs to only include elements that have changed.

Right now, my code returns everything correctly concatenated but it also returns elements that did not need any changes.

My sample XML has 3 items, the first does not have any changes so it does not need to be returned.
The second has a change in Quantity the third needs the concatenation part so those last two are the only ones that should be returned.

Sample XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<document>
    <myObjects>
        <Base>
            <Code>11</Code>
            <Item>216</Item>
            <Build>BH</Build>
            <Quantity>203</Quantity>
            <Description>BH-203-216|Description 1</Description>
        </Base>
        
        <Base>
            <Code>19</Code>
            <Item>169</Item>
            <Build>FM</Build>
            <Quantity>2</Quantity>
            <Description>FM-201-169|Description 2</Description>
        </Base>
        
        <Base>
            <Code>20</Code>
            <Item>169</Item>
            <Build>MM</Build>
            <Quantity></Quantity>
            <Description>Description 3</Description>
        </Base>


    </myObjects>
</document>
```

The resulting XML should look like this:

```
<document>
   <myObjects>
      <Base>
         <Code>19</Code>
         <Description>FM-2-169|Description 2</Description>
      </Base>
      <Base>
         <Code>20</Code>
         <Description>MM-169|Description 3</Description>
      </Base>
   </myObjects>
</document>
```

My XSL code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" media-type="xml/plain"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- drop elements with concat-->
    <xsl:template match="Base">
        <xsl:variable name="currentPre" select="substring-before(Description,'|')" />
        <xsl:variable name="currentPost" select="substring-after(Description,'|')" />
        <xsl:variable name="NewPre" select="string-join((Build,Quantity/text(),Item/text()), '-')" />
 
        <xsl:copy>
        
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(contains(Description, '|'))">
                    <xsl:variable name="emptyDes" select="Description" />
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Code"/>
                    <Description>
                        <xsl:value-of select="string-join((Build,Quantity/text(),Item/text()), '-'), Description" separator="|"/>
                    </Description>
                </xsl:when>
                    
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Code"/>
                    <Description>
                        <xsl:value-of select="string-join((Build,Quantity/text(),Item/text()), '-'), $currentPost" separator="|"/>
                    </Description>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What in the data tells you that an element has "changed"?

Comment: @jim-garrison I need to check if the part before the pipe character is different that a new concatenation

Comment: You have to build the new concatenation and then compare it to the old one to select "changed" nodes.

Comment: The third also has a change in quantity. But that is not the reason to be returned? Since you always seems to construct the Description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you test whether the newly constructed `Description` value is equal to the current `Description` value, and only copy when different, you can also consolidate the logic for generating those items:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" media-type="xml/plain"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- drop elements with concat-->
    <xsl:template match="Base">
        <xsl:variable name="currentPre" select="substring-before(Description,'|')" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="currentPost" select="substring-after(Description,'|')[normalize-space()]" as="xs:string?" />
        <xsl:variable name="NewPost" select="($currentPost,Description)[1]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="NewPre" select="string-join((Build,Quantity/text(),Item/text()), '-')" />
        <xsl:variable name="NewDescription" select="string-join(($NewPre, $NewPost), '|')"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(Description eq $NewDescription)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Code"/>
                <Description><xsl:value-of select="$NewDescription"/></Description>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>   
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm new to XSL, with your code I get an error 

XPST0017 XPath syntax error at char 0 on line 16 in {head(($currentPost,Description...}:
    Unknown system function head()

Comment: Sorry, that is an XSLT 3 function, not available in XSLT 2.0. I'll update to instead use a predicate on the sequence `($currentPost,Description)[1]`